# RDD intersections

Tags: scala, intersection, rdd

I have a query about intersection between two RDDs.

My first RDD has a list of elements like this:

```
A = List(1,2,3,4), List(4,5,6), List(8,3,1),List(1,6,8,9,2)
```

And the second RDD is like this:

```
B = (1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9)
```

(I could store B in memory as a `Set` but not the first one.)

I would like to do an intersection of each element in A with B

```
List(1,2,3,4).intersect((1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9))
List(4,5,6).intersect((1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9))
List(8,3,1).intersect((1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9))
List(1,6,8,9,2).intersect((1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9))
```

How can I do this in Scala?

Comment: Check this out: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#intersection(org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)
Took me 10 seconds  to find on google.

Comment: Thanks! But i doubt it works in scala. I get an error saying RDD is not a valid argument to pass to intersection

Comment: This then?https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@intersection(org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)

Comment: Sorry if my question's not clear :) But what i want to do is an intersection of each element of one RDD with another RDD.       
val output =  a4.map(v => v.intersect(a6))                                                                            and i get this [ERROR] /LabWork/BigData/MiniProject/TwitterProject/src/main/scala/community/spark/twitter/TestPrint.scala:41: error: value intersect is not a member of Iterable[String]

Comment: Don't intersect with RDD. You said you could store it in memory. Do that, store it as Seq, and then `a.map(_.interesect(bAsSeq))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`val result = rdd.map( x => x.intersect(B))`

Both `B` and `rdd` have to have the same type (in this case `List[Int]`). Also, note that if B is big but fits in memory, you would want to probably broadcast it as [documented here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables).

```
scala> val B = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9)
B: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9)

scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(List(1,2,3,4), List(4,5,6), List(8,3,1),List(1,6,8,9,2)))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[List[Int]] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:21

scala> rdd.map( x => x.intersect(B)).collect.mkString("\n")
res3: String = 
List(1, 2, 3, 4)
List(4, 5, 6)
List(8, 3, 1)
List(1, 6, 8, 9, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks KrisP! I was doing what you suggested but was getting type cast errors earlier. It works now.